# The building can/could collapse at any minute

Tags: grammar, word-choice, idiomatic-language

> *We can't go in there. The building can/could collapse at any minute.*

1. Are 'can' and 'could' equally natural here?
2. Would using 'could' sound formal?

Answer (score 1):

"Can" sounds more like a statement of fact, and "could" sounds more like a possibility. We usually can't be certain that an individual building will collapse, so "could" sounds much more natural here. On [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=can+collapse+at+any%2Ccould+collapse+at+any&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3), for example, "could collapse at any" surpasses "can collapse at any" by a factor of 10.

Here, "could" doesn't sound particularly formal or informal.